# Diffraction of light around an object & human perception

Tags: visible-light, diffraction

> A wave exhibits diffraction when it encounters an obstacle that bends
>   the wave or when it spreads after emerging from an opening.
>   Diffraction effects are more pronounced when the size of the obstacle
>   or opening is comparable to the wavelength of the wave.

(maybe physics stackExchange isn't the proper place to ask this question?)

I was wondering if we (our vision perception) notice this phenomenon? Light diffraction around an edge/object is clearly visible to the human eye (e.g. edgy/fuzzy shadow) but when we are looking at the edge/object directly I can not make clear to myself if I/we notice this phenomenon or not?

Shouldn't the perception of this phenomenon be clearly noticed by us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://labman.phys.utk.edu/phys136/modules/m9/diff.htm) is an example of a multi-slit experiment where you can see the diffraction.

It would be *very* difficult, if not impossible, to detect whether light coming around a corner was there because of diffraction or because you were actually looking at the light source.

However, if you set up a slit experiment, then shine a light through the hole, you could replace the wall with your eye, and you would be able to see the light from multiple locations, not just directly through the slit. Although it would still be more obvious if you just looked at the wall with your eye (and safer, since they usually use lasers in the experiments).